# Remove SCP banner in unix scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scp, banner

How can I remove the banner while you perform scp to another server? 
I've been tried the `-q` option but it only remove the transfer bar, I've tried the same option using `ssh` and it's working without any issues.

```
scp -q "file" ip_address:/directory/To/Copy
```

any idea?

Comment: I've tested it on Ubuntu 14 and SLC 6 and don't see any banner. What's your host and client setup? What kind of banner do you see?

Comment: When you're connected to another server you see the banner for the server, somethings a message like "this server is monitored and any...blah blah"

Comment: Not sure, if this is what you want, but you can redirect the output from scp with `scp -q "file" ip_address:/directory/To/Copy > /dev/null` or if you also want to suppress stderr `scp -q "file" ip_address:/directory/To/Copy 2>&1 > /dev/null`

Comment: awesome! that worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can suppress the standard output of a command, by redirecting it to `/dev/null`:

```
scp -q "file" ip_address:/directory/To/Copy > /dev/null
```

If you also want to suppress messages printed to `stderr`, you run

```
scp -q "file" ip_address:/directory/To/Copy > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: [shellcheck: To redirect stdout+stderr, 2>&1 must be last (or use '{ cmd > file; } 2>&1' to clarify).](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2069)

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disable banner is sshd_config and also set `UsePAM no` resolves the problem of banner text corrupting files on SCP.